# How to send a javascript value to php and get it displayed in redirected page

Tags: javascript, php

I was trying to assigna  javascript value from one page to another. 
The concept is, User plays this thing of spin the wheel, he gets a task and he gets redirected to another page. There he should see his task. Sounds simple but being a new i am in trouble.

Here's what I have coded so far

My game.js file

```js
// the game itself
var game;
// the spinning wheel
var wheel; 
// can the wheel spin?
var canSpin;
// slices (prizes) placed in the wheel
var slices = 8;
// prize names, starting from 12 o'clock going clockwise
var slicePrizes = ["Task 8", "Task 1", "Task 2", "Task 3", "Task 4", "Task 5", "Task 6", "Task 7"];
// the prize you are about to win
var prize;
// text field where to show the prize
var prizeText;

window.onload = function() { 
     // creation of a 458x488 game
 game = new Phaser.Game(458, 488, Phaser.AUTO, "");
     // adding "PlayGame" state
     game.state.add("PlayGame",playGame);
     // launching "PlayGame" state
     game.state.start("PlayGame");
}

// PLAYGAME STATE
 
var playGame = function(game){};

playGame.prototype = {
     // function to be executed once the state preloads
     preload: function(){
          // preloading graphic assets
          game.load.image("wheel", "wheel.png");
  game.load.image("pin", "pin.png");     
     },
     // funtion to be executed when the state is created
   create: function(){
          // giving some color to background
    game.stage.backgroundColor = "#880044";
          // adding the wheel in the middle of the canvas
    wheel = game.add.sprite(game.width / 2, game.width / 2, "wheel");
          // setting wheel registration point in its center
          wheel.anchor.set(0.5);
          // adding the pin in the middle of the canvas
          var pin = game.add.sprite(game.width / 2, game.width / 2, "pin");
          // setting pin registration point in its center
          pin.anchor.set(0.5);
          // adding the text field
          prizeText = game.add.text(game.world.centerX, 480, "");
          // setting text field registration point in its center
          prizeText.anchor.set(0.5);
          // aligning the text to center
          prizeText.align = "center";
          // the game has just started = we can spin the wheel
          canSpin = true;
          // waiting for your input, then calling "spin" function
          game.input.onDown.add(this.spin, this);  
 },
     // function to spin the wheel
     spin(){
          // can we spin the wheel?
          if(canSpin){  
               // resetting text field
               prizeText.text = "";
               // the wheel will spin round from 2 to 4 times. This is just coreography
               var rounds = game.rnd.between(2, 4);
               // then will rotate by a random number from 0 to 360 degrees. This is the actual spin
               var degrees = game.rnd.between(0, 360);
               // before the wheel ends spinning, we already know the prize according to "degrees" rotation and the number of slices
               prize = slices - 1 - Math.floor(degrees / (360 / slices));
               // now the wheel cannot spin because it's already spinning
               canSpin = false;
               // animation tweeen for the spin: duration 3s, will rotate by (360 * rounds + degrees) degrees
               // the quadratic easing will simulate friction
               var spinTween = game.add.tween(wheel).to({
                    angle: 360 * rounds + degrees
               }, 3000, Phaser.Easing.Quadratic.Out, true);
               // once the tween is completed, call winPrize function
               spinTween.onComplete.add(this.winPrize, this);
          }
     },
     // function to assign the prize
     winPrize(){
          // now we can spin the wheel again
          canSpin = true;
          // writing the prize you just won
          prizeText.text = slicePrizes[prize];
          

          window.location="http://Localhost/example/page2.php";
           
     }

               
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript to PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798926/javascript-to-php)

Comment: Hi Neil, looks like homework... ;) First, please break the problems down and elaborate on the things that work and doesn't work. For the things that don't work, mention what you have researched or attempts to resolve them. If you just post questions without expressing your effort to resolve it yourself, your question may be flagged as "Lazy, Debug-It-For-Me" and may be closed. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry Duke, My bad. I was too hurried. I hope i have explained it a bit down below.

Answer (score 0):

```js
winPrize(){
          // now we can spin the wheel again
          canSpin = true;
          // writing the prize you just won
          prizeText.text = slicePrizes[prize];
          

          window.location="http://Localhost/example/page2.php";
           
     }
```

Here,
PrizText.text = slicePrizes[prize];
prints my prize in the same html/php page. However I was trying to redirect a user/participant to another page  with 
window.location="http://Localhost/example/page2.php";
and get his/her task displayed there. 
I tried and researched every bit of information found in web but nothing seemed to work out. I tried making and assigning php variable and a hidden form to get that variable to next landing page. But didn't worked